# ListView SQLite error

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to make listview using this code

KUHAPDatabase.java

```
private static final String LABEL = "DatabaseUU";
public static final String PASAL = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
public static final String ISI = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;
public static final String BAB = "BAB";
public static final String KATEGORI = "KATEGORI";

private static final String NAMA_DB = "undang";
static final String NAMA_TABEL = "kolom";
private static final int VERSI_DATABASE = 2;

private final DictionaryOpenHelper bukaDB;
private static final HashMap<String,String> untukHubungKolom = untukHubungKolom();

public KUHAPDatabase(Context context) {
 bukaDB = new DictionaryOpenHelper(context);
}

private static HashMap<String,String> untukHubungKolom() {
    HashMap<String,String> hubung = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hubung.put(PASAL, PASAL);
    hubung.put(ISI, ISI);
    hubung.put(BAB, BAB);
    hubung.put(KATEGORI, KATEGORI);
    hubung.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
            BaseColumns._ID);
    hubung.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
    hubung.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
    return hubung;
}

public Cursor getWord(String brsID, String[] klm) {
    String plhUU = "rowId = ?";
    String[] kolomUU = new String[] {brsID};

    return query(plhUU, kolomUU, klm);         
}

public Cursor getWordMatches(String cariLokasiUU, String[] klm) {
    String plhUU = PASAL + " MATCH ?";
    String[] gudangUU = new String[] {cariLokasiUU+"*"};

    return query(plhUU, gudangUU, klm);         
}

private Cursor query(String pilih, String[] penyimpananUU, String[] klm) {

    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(NAMA_TABEL);
    builder.setProjectionMap(untukHubungKolom);

    Cursor cursor = builder.query(bukaDB.getReadableDatabase(),
            klm, pilih, penyimpananUU, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    return cursor;
}

private static class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final Context BukaDB;
    private SQLiteDatabase DB;

    private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + NAMA_TABEL +
                " USING fts3 (" +
                PASAL + ", " +
                KATEGORI + ", " +
                BAB + ", " +
                ISI + ");";

    DictionaryOpenHelper(Context bantuantukBukaDBUU) {
        super(bantuantukBukaDBUU, NAMA_DB, null, VERSI_DATABASE);
        BukaDB = bantuantukBukaDBUU;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase buatDB) {
        DB = buatDB;
        DB.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
        inputkanDBUU();
    }

    private void inputkanDBUU() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    inputkanUU();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void inputkanUU() throws IOException {
        Log.d(LABEL, "Harap tunggu, sedang memasukan undang-undang kedalam database...");
        final Resources asalUU = BukaDB.getResources();
        InputStream inputUU = asalUU.openRawResource(R.raw.input_undang_undang);
        BufferedReader bacaUU = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputUU));

        try {
            String jajarUU;
            while ((jajarUU = bacaUU.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] daftarUU = TextUtils.split(jajarUU, "-");
                if (daftarUU.length < 2) continue;
                long uuID = inputUU(daftarUU[0].trim(), daftarUU[1].trim(), daftarUU[2].trim(), daftarUU[3].trim());
                if (uuID < 0) {
                    Log.e(LABEL, "Maaf, tidak bisa menambah undang-undang: " + daftarUU[0].trim());
                }
            }
        } finally {
         bacaUU.close();
        }
        Log.d(LABEL, "Selesai menunggu undang.");
    }

    public long inputUU(String pasal, String isi, String bab, String kategori) {
        ContentValues barisUU = new ContentValues();
        barisUU.put(PASAL, pasal);
        barisUU.put(ISI, isi);
        barisUU.put(BAB, bab);
        barisUU.put(KATEGORI, kategori);

        return DB.insert(NAMA_TABEL, null, barisUU);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase ubahDB, int versiDulu, int versiTerbaru) {
        Log.w(LABEL, "Database di upgrade dari versi " + versiDulu + " ke "
                + versiTerbaru + ", dan akan menghapus semua data yg lama");
        ubahDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NAMA_TABEL);
        onCreate(ubahDB);
    }
}

public Cursor fetchAllUndang(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    return db.query("WISATA", new String[] { PASAL, ISI }, null, null,
            null, null, null);
}
```

And this

DataListView.java

```
private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
private String tableName = KUHAPDatabase.NAMA_TABEL;
private SQLiteDatabase undang;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    openAndQueryDatabase();

    displayResultList();


}
private void displayResultList() {
    TextView tView = new TextView(this);
    tView.setText("This data is retrieved from the database and only 4 " +
            "of the results are displayed");
    getListView().addHeaderView(tView);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

}
private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
    try {
        KUHAPDatabase dbHelper = new KUHAPDatabase(this.getApplicationContext());
        undang = KUHAPDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = undang.rawQuery("SELECT BAB, KATEGORI FROM " +
                tableName, null);

        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("BAB"));
                    String age = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("KATEGORI"));
                    results.add("Name: " + firstName + ",KATEGORI: " + age);
                }while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }          
    } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    } 

}
```

It result in error. I want my listview generate data from my database, I'm still new in android, can anyone help ?

Comment: What is error ? Post Logcat

Comment: The error is in Datalistview.java "undang = KUHAPDatabase.getWritableDatabase();", it said "the method getwritable database undevined for the type KUHAP database"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error is in Datalistview.java "undang = KUHAPDatabase.getWritableDatabase();", it said "the method getwritable database undevined for the type KUHAP database"

Your error is pretty self-explanatory. The `KUHAPDatabase` class doesn't have a `getWritableDatabase()` method.

The `getWriteableDatabase()` method is defined in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. In your code, the `DictionaryOpenHelper` is the one that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`, so that is the class you must use to get a writable database.

Comment: Oh yeah ! the error is gone now ! thanks ! like i say, i'm still new in android and this is the first time I asking question, sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the help !